# Google Apps Script not sending email

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-analytics, google-analytics-4, google-ad-manager

We are trying to get e-mail notifications in cases there would be some dramatic changes in our revenue data. Could anyone please indicate possible errors why it wouldn't send e-mail?

```
function sendEmail() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1"); 
  const data = sh.getRange("B2:L80" + sh.getLastRow()).getValues();
  data.forEach(r=>{
     let overdueValue = r[9];  
     if (overdueValue === "TRUE"){
         let name = r[10];
         let message = "Reach out to " + name;
         let subject = "Reach out to this person.";
         //MailApp.sendEmail("xxxxx@gmail.com", subject, message);
         GmailApp.sendEmail("xxxx@gmail.com", subject, message);  
     }
  });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing `if (overdueValue === "TRUE")` to `if (overdueValue === true)`

**Updated Code:**

```
function sendEmail() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1"); 
  const data = sh.getRange("B2:L80" + sh.getLastRow()).getValues();
  data.forEach(r=>{
     let overdueValue = r[9];  
     if (overdueValue === true){
         let name = r[10];
         let message = "Reach out to " + name;
         let subject = "Reach out to this person.";
         //MailApp.sendEmail("xxxxx@gmail.com", subject, message);
         GmailApp.sendEmail("xxxx@gmail.com", subject, message);  
     }
  });
}
```

**Notes:**

- overdueValue is a [boolean](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Boolean) so trying to check if the value is a [string](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String) will always end up being false.
- You could also convert overdueValue to a string which could then be checked as you previously did. You'd just need to change the capitalization of TRUE: `if (overdueValue.toString() === "true")`